# Vista Group Policy Editor via run "gpedit.msc" not found

Tags: windows-vista, group-policy

When I try and run the group policy editor, via gpedit.msc, I get an error message "Windows could not find gpedit.msc, please try again, etc." How can I fix this and access the Group Policy editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What edition of Vista do you have?

The group policy editor is only available in the Business, Enterprise and Ultimate edition. Home Basic and Home Premium do not have it.

Comment: Oh, I have home premium. Is there any equivalent that I can use?